# ImageView in CollapsingToolbarLayout not covering full height?

Tags: android, android-layout, android-design-library, androiddesignsupport

I have some issues trying to implement the new `CollapsingToolbarLayout`. Scrolling, expanding and collapsing do work fine, but my `ImageView` (no matter what type of resource I set) does not cover the full height of the expanded toolbar. See here:

[image: expanded]
[image: collapsed]

Here I set `android:src="@color/red"` on the image view, but it never covers the real toolbar. It doesn't work with bitmaps either. I am posting my layout below.

```
<android.support.v4.widget.DrawerLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    xmlns:tools="http://schemas.android.com/tools"
    xmlns:app="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res-auto"
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="match_parent"
    android:fitsSystemWindows="true">

    <!-- content -->
    <android.support.design.widget.CoordinatorLayout
        android:fitsSystemWindows="true"
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="match_parent">
        <android.support.design.widget.AppBarLayout
            android:layout_height="@dimen/appbar_expanded_height"
            android:layout_width="match_parent"
            android:theme="@style/ThemeOverlay.AppCompat.Dark.ActionBar"
            android:fitsSystemWindows="true">
            <android.support.design.widget.CollapsingToolbarLayout
                android:layout_height="match_parent"
                android:layout_width="match_parent"
                app:layout_scrollFlags="scroll|exitUntilCollapsed"
                app:expandedTitleMarginStart="48dp"
                app:expandedTitleMarginEnd="64dp"
                app:contentScrim="?attr/colorPrimary"
                android:fitsSystemWindows="true">

                <ImageView
                    android:layout_width="match_parent"
                    android:layout_height="match_parent"
                    android:fitsSystemWindows="true"
                    android:src="@color/red_600"
                    android:scaleType="centerCrop"
                    app:layout_collapseMode="parallax"
                    />
                <android.support.v7.widget.Toolbar
                    android:id="@+id/toolbar"
                    app:layout_collapseMode="pin"
                    android:layout_width="match_parent"
                    android:layout_height="?attr/actionBarSize">
                </android.support.v7.widget.Toolbar>

            </android.support.design.widget.CollapsingToolbarLayout>
        </android.support.design.widget.AppBarLayout>

        <!-- I load fragments here -->
        <FrameLayout
            android:id="@+id/fragment_content"
            android:layout_width="match_parent"
            android:layout_height="match_parent"
            app:layout_behavior="@string/appbar_scrolling_view_behavior"/>
    </android.support.design.widget.CoordinatorLayout>

    <!-- nav drawer -->
    <fragment
        android:layout_width="@dimen/drawer_width"
        android:layout_height="match_parent"
        android:layout_gravity="start"/>
</android.support.v4.widget.DrawerLayout>
```

Seems to me that the only difference with, for example, the cheese-Chris Banes-app, is that I'm giving `app:layout_behavior` to a `FrameLayout`. However, inside that frame I load fragments that have a `NestedScrollView` as the root view, and this seems to work fine.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

I found the blue strip was the toolbar background. Namely, I had:

```
<item name="toolbarStyle">@style/MyToolbarStyle</item>
```

in my theme, and:

```
<style name="MyToolbarStyle">
    <item name="android:background">?attr/colorPrimary</item>
</style>
```

I used to have this to tint toolbars with `colorPrimary`. However if you want to move to the design library, you should **get rid** of it: the collapsed toolbar color is already managed by the `app:contentScrim` attribute on the `CollapsingToolbarLayout`.

Comment: I have the exact same issue where my image view is always below the Toolbar. I'm not sure I understand how you fixed this.

Comment: I removed any toolbar's android:background attribute, both in styles and in the layout file.

Answer (score 7):

I had the same problem, the collapsing toolbar did not cover the full height of Image, But fixed with removing single line from the `AppBarLayout`. That is you just need remove `android:fitsSystemWindows="true` and you are done.

```
<android.support.design.widget.AppBarLayout
        android:layout_height="@dimen/appbar_expanded_height"
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:theme="@style/ThemeOverlay.AppCompat.Dark.ActionBar"
        android:fitsSystemWindows="true">
```

remove the last line, that is as.

```
 android:fitsSystemWindows="true"
```

that's it, good to go...